# How detect right mouse button press?

Tags: c++, linux, mouse

I want to detect right mouse button press in c++. I am programing in Linux OS.

I try to use  `XGrabPointer(display, root_win, False,ButtonPressMask,  GrabModeSync, GrabModeSync, root_win, None, CurrentTime)` and  `XWindowEvent(display, root_win, ButtonPressMask , &report)` function for my project, but there is no answer.

My code is:

```
Display* display = NULL;
display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
Screen *screen; Window root_win;
XEvent report;
int screen_num;
int check;

screen_num = DefaultScreen(display);
screen = XScreenOfDisplay(display, screen_num);
root_win = RootWindow(display, XScreenNumberOfScreen(screen));
check = XGrabPointer(display, root_win, False,ButtonPressMask, GrabModeSync, GrabModeSync, root_win, None, CurrentTime);
XAllowEvents(display, SyncPointer, CurrentTime); XWindowEvent(display, root_win, ButtonPressMask , &report);
```

Comment: Mouse clicks are event based notifications that your register against. with what framework are you planning to work GTK, QT ?

Comment: I do suggest to use Qt. However, we cannot answer unless you give a lot more details, and some source code. What is your program intended to do?

Comment: Good luck. X11 is not a framework (but a low level library), and you'll need months to understand how it should be used, notably its interaction with the desktop or window manager. Mastering [ICCCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icccm) and [EWMH](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/wm-spec) will take you many months, and details count.

Comment: Did you remember to ask `XSelectInput` for `ButtonPressMask` and `ButtonReleaseMask`?

Comment: No I am not using XSelectInput.

Comment: Oh, I see, yes. Can you please check the return value from `XAllowEvents` I have a feeling that it might be returning `BadRequest`.

Comment: Actually, ignore that. I just checked the source code of Xlib, and it turns out that XAllowEvents always returns 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you most use x11 library.it is very simple
(http://www.wikihow.com/Configure-X11-in-Linux)